# Singletons in metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm trying to prove that singletons in a metric space with the usual metric are closed.

Does this argument make sense?

Any Cauchy sequence in a singleton E is a constant sequence and thus must converge. Therefore $E$ must be closed by the proposition that a subspace $E$ of $X$ is closed iff E is complete.

Comment: The "proposition" you quote is false. What about metric spaces that are themselves not complete? The whole space is closed but it isn't complete.

Comment: Hint: The complement of a closed set is open.

Comment: It must converge, and its limit must be the singleton in question. Thus the closure of the singleton is the singleton itself, so it is closed.

Comment: The only limit point of the set $\{x\}$, with $x\in X$ is $x$ itself. Hence every singleton is closed.

Comment: @Mirko You still have to show that the constant sequence has no other limits, or prove unicity of sequential limits first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to show $X \setminus \{x\}$ is open. So if $p \neq x$, we know that $r = d(p,x) > 0$. Now show that $B(p,r) \subseteq X \setminus \{x\}$.